# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website and writing the data to CSV file (successfully). I am facing two challenges:

1. Data in CSV file is saving in ROWS not in Columns.
2. Site has pages, 1,2,3,4...Next I cannot browse through all pages to scrape the data. Data is scrapped only from the first page.

Error:

```
if last_link.startswith('Next'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Code:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://localhost:8088/wiki.html'

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find('table', {'class' : 'tab_operator'})

list_of_rows = []
for rows in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in rows.findAll('td'):
        list_of_links = []
        for links in cell.findAll('a'):
            text = links.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
            list_of_links.append(text)
        list_of_rows.append(list_of_links)

outfile = open('./outfile.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)

try:
    last_link = soup.find('table', {'id' : 'str_nav'}).find_all('a')[-1]
    if last_link.startswith('Next'):
        next_url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(last_link['href'])
        url = urllib.parse.urlunparse((base_url_parts.scheme, base_url_parts.netloc, next_url_parts.path, next_url_parts.params, next_url_parts.query, next_url_parts.fragment))

except ValueError:
    print("Oops! Try again...")
```

Website HTML sample code:

```
### Numbers to scrape ###

<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-top:20px;" class="tab_operator">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top">
<a href="http://localhost:8088/wiki/9400000">9400000</a><br>
<a href="http://localhost:8088/wiki/9400001">9400001</a><br>
</td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>

###  Paging Sample Code: ###

<div class="pstrnav" align="center">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" border="0" id="str_nav">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#f5f5f5;font-weight:bold;">1</td>
<td><a href="http://localhost:8088/wiki/2">2</a></td>
<td><a href="http://localhost:8088/wiki/3">3</a></td>
<td><a href="http://localhost:8088/wiki/4">4</a></td>
<td><a href="http://localhost:8088/wiki/2">Next &gt;&gt;</a></td>
<td><a href="http://localhost:8088/wiki/100">Last</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`last_link` is a tag object, *not* a string. BeautifulSoup treats any attribute name on a tag that is not an existing attribute or method as a *tag search* instead. Because there is no `startswith` tag in the link, that search returns `None`, and it is that object you are trying to call:

```
>>> last_link = soup.find('table', {'id' : 'str_nav'}).find_all('a')[-1]
>>> last_link
<a href="http://localhost:8088/wiki/100">Last</a>
>>> last_link.startswith is None
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

You want to test the *contained text* instead:

```
if last_link.get_text(strip=True).startswith('Next'):
```

This uses the [`Tag.get_text()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to access all text in the link; using this method works even if there are other tags contained in the link (like `<b>` or `<i>` markup).

You probably want to search directly for the `Next` link here:

```
import re

table = soup.select_one('table#str_nav')
last_link = table.find('a', text=re.compile('^Next'))
```

The regular expression specifies that only directly contained text starting with `Next` allows an `a` tag to match.

Comment: did the changes as suggested... `table = soup.select_one('table#str_nav')
        last_link = table.find('a', text=re.compile('^Next'))
        if last_link.get_text(strip=True).startswith('Next'):` .....but still getting the error message: `table = soup.select_one('table#str_nav')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: @Overflow: `select_one` requires BeautifulSoup 4.4.0 or newer (released about 6 months ago, IIRC).

Comment: @Overflow: use `table = soup.select('table#str_nav')[0]` if your bs4 installation is older.

Comment: Thanks. The error is gone but out the file result is same..only first page data, not navigating to remaining pages..